# length of fence in feet

Tags: algebra-precalculus

suppose that,we have following problem

A straight fence is to be constructed from posts $6$ inches wide and separated by lengths of chain $5$ feet long. If a certain fence begins and ends with a post, which of the following could be the length of the fence in feet? ($12$ inches = $1$ foot).

possible answers are :

$A. 17$

$B. 28$

$C. 35$

$D. 39$

$E. 50$

basic problem which i have,is understanding of question:
because $12$ inches =$1$feet,it means that $6$inches=$0.5$foot,now we have length  we have $5$ feet and width  $0.5$ width,what is asking exactly question?perimeter?also what does mean that certain fence starts and with a post,does it create something like circle?please help me

Comment: http://www.beatthegmat.com/a-straight-fence-is-to-be-constructed-from-posts-6-inches-wi-t224733.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says the fence is a straight line. To work as a fence there must be a post at each end, so the number of posts is one more than the number of chains between them. Let $n$ be the number of chains. There is a post for each chain and one post over.

So you have a formula $5.5n+0.5$. Which answer can be written in that form?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to create a circle (it doesn't need to be closed). They're just asking which of the following lengths can be constructed out of increments of 5 and .5, where there is exactly one more post than fence length.

Comment: sorry how?they are asking linear combination of $5$ and $0.5$?

Comment: Yes, linear combinations, but you can't have 3 posts and 1 fence length, for instance; that would not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying that it forms a circle. Because it starts with a post and ends with a post, there is one more post than the number of lengths:

$$l=\frac{1}{2}(n+1)+5n$$

Where $n$ is the number of lengths there are (a positive integer).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose ***n*** to be the number of chains used for making the fence.Now the length of chain is 5 feet so the length of chain in the fence will be ***5 x n***.Also 0.5 feet will be length of posts.And fence starts and ends with a post,so chain has to be in between to posts.Thus there will always be ***n+1*** posts in the fence.So the total length of the fence will be ***5n + (((n+1) x 0.5)***.Which can be simplified to ***5.5n + 0.5***.By putting values in the last equation you will get all the options correct **except** option **C**.